# How do I install Dell 2150cdn printer

Tags: drivers, printing, dell

Love Ubuntu but cannot get printer to work. It's a Dell 2150cdn colour laser printer.

I went to settings and tried to add printer and tried all various options but they alll jang for over an hour. Tried in both Gnome and KDE. Chose option to install openprint but it does not load, just hangs.

Loaded openprint fron software centre but doesnt seem to make any difference.

Searched web and found dell PDL file, d/led and installed. Printer works but does not print documents, just lots of blank pages with 1 line of symbols on some of them.

Went to dell site and d/l'd driver file but also makes no difference.

Stuck now and need to get printer working or forced to retreat back to windoze.

Any advice?

Cheers

Brian

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late, but I've been facing this issue since I switched to Pop!_OS. Previously, I used Windows, but I managed to resolve the problem on my own.

Firstly, I downloaded the old driver for my 2150cn from the official website. Then, I created a 32-bit Linux virtual machine, specifically Linux Mint 19 32-bit. In this virtual machine, I installed Alien to convert the RPM file to a DEB file. Here's how to proceed:

Add the Universe repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Update the package list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install Alien:

```
sudo apt-get install alien
```

To convert the RPM to DEB, use the following command:

```
sudo alien ./Dell-2150-Color-Printer-1.0-1.i686.rpm
```

Once the file is converted, copy the DEB file to your Pop!_OS system and install it using apt:

```
sudo apt install ./Dell-2150-Color-Printer-1.0-1.i686.deb
```

Afterward, configure your Dell 2150cn printer normally, and it should print in color without any issues.

If you don't want to go through the conversion process yourself, I've already done it. Here's the link to the converted DEB file: https://mega.nz/file/BWgWkRLI#nta6kO2KBMMdWu8OxyGYdDMfWkXxSkE3frzsDb6PKHM

I hope this helps Dell 2150cn users on Linux.